# Unity Rotation & Quaternions

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity and I have a question.

I dont understand why this line resets the rotation to 0,0,0. All I'm doing is re-assigning its euler values?

```
transform.rotation = 
             Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x,
                              transform.rotation.y,
                              transform.rotation.z);
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I need to lock one axis and keep the others changing. So I thought I could do it like this after the changes in x and z axes occur:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x,
                                      LOCKED ROTATION VALUE,
                                      transform.rotation.z);
```

I'm sure its simple but I cant find out whats wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must not put a value from `transform.rotation` into `Quaternion.Euler`. This will not do what you think. `transform.rotation` returns a Quaternion and Quaternions are complex numbers, not float. E.g. a rotation of 180 degrees on the y axis would be a Quaternion of `w = 0, x = 0, y = 1, z = 0`.

Comment: **Never** use Quaternions for any reason. You may have seen them mentioned online, which is confusing.  To rotate an object in Unity, use "Rotate".  You can also use "eulerAngles" in many cases.  Enjoy!

Comment: @JoeBlow completly disagree, please re-check what are the advantages of using quaternions and how they are far better than ones you proposed and only when you'll understand the problem properly then I bet you'll change your mind. There is nice article on gamasutra about them.

Comment: Hi Vilo.  It is inconceivable that the OP understands quaternions.  **Never use quaternions** unless you are **completely** expert with abstract, four dimensional, imaginary plane mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is some documentation with transform.Rotate()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html). I'd use this one for rotating.

```
// Here is an example if you want to just rotate the Z axis.
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 10f) * Time.deltaTime);
```

[Also, here is some other documentation on Quaternion](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html).  You could use functions like RotateTowards.

If your game object has a rigidbody on it then you can lock the rotation of it in Unity. Click on the game object and under the Rigidbody component click Constraints and then click the axis under Freeze Rotation.

Comment: My object doesnt have a Rigidbody and I dont need to have one.

Comment: @Sangratura - For sure. Sorry I didn't make it clear that you only need to use Rotate(). Just giving you options.

Comment: hi @Sangratura.  It's absolutely essential that you ***do not use*** quaternions.  simply use transform.eulerAngles if (for some reason) you want to set the eulerAngles.

Answer (score 2):

You are using transform.rotation as if it is exposing Euler angles (which it is not).  If you want the Euler angles from your rotation, you have to do this:

```
transform.rotation = 
             Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
                              transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,
                              transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
```